# \cite showing as [?]

Tags: bibtex

Trying to do a bibtex, however in the document it is showing as [?]

in my bibfile.bib I have

```
@Misc{PaymentCardIndustry,
howpublished = {\url{https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-1.pdf/}},
note = {Accessed September 25, 2015},
title = {Payment Card Industry
Data Security Standard},
author = {Payment Card Industry}
}
```

In my packages I have 
\usepackage{cite}

and I cite the reference as 
\cite{PaymentCardIndustry}

Comment: You have to compile using `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex` and `pdflatex`.

Comment: You must run the sequence: `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex`. You `latex` the file ending in `.tex`, and `bibtex` the file ending in `aux`. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/8528).

Comment: Recompile the process several times.